# Detect and Setup alerts on clusters being dropped from envoy

Tags: reverse-proxy, envoyproxy

We are using envoy as a reverse proxy and have few static/dynamic clusters. I need a way to monitor all the static clusters (all are critical) and create alerts whenever any of them is not reachable. The alert will help team take timely action.

I am new to envoy and exploring its features. It would be helpful if someone can answer/ point me to right resource.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible out-of-the-box with Envoy. **But** you can use something like Prometheus and Alertmanager to monitor and create alerts for your clusters.

If you have admin interface set up (https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.1/operations/admin), you can query `/stats/prometheus` to get some metrics.

The following metrics can be interesting in your case :

- `envoy_cluster_update_failure{envoy_cluster_name="my-cluster"}` : increase when the cluster is **not reachable**
- `envoy_cluster_update_success{envoy_cluster_name="my-cluster"}` : increase when the cluster is reachable

I am not an expert in Prometheus/Alertmanager, but something like :

```
increase(envoy_cluster_update_failure{envoy_cluster_name="my-cluster"}[1m]) > 0
```

should trigger alerts when the cluster `my-cluster` become not reachable.